# Python pandas: change one column conditional on another

Tags: python, pandas

How can I reverse the sign in the quantity column whenever the side column has a sell? All other values should not be changed. The following is simply not working, it has no effect.

```
df[df['side'] == 'Sell']['quantity'] = df[df['side'] == 'Sell']['quantity'] * -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [Pandas indexing documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing), and never use chain indexing per your example when setting values.

```
df.loc[df.side == 'Sell', 'quantity'] *= -1
```